# Is there a way to know whether Tracer is success fully connected to jaeger backend server in jaegerclientcpp?

Tags: c++, jaeger, opentracing, distributed-tracing

In `jaeger-client-cpp` when I connect my `Tracer` variable to jaeger backend (I m using `jaeger-all-in-one` server) then upon successful connection `LOG INFO` message is shown telling me the connection is successful, but when connection is unsuccessful is just shows `LOG ERROR` message telling me that connection with server not successful.

So is there any way to check this programatically about the status of connection of `Tracer` with server.

`OS-ubuntu 18.04`
`jaeger-client-cpp-v0.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <jaegertracing/net/IPAddress.h>
#include <jaegertracing/net/Socket.h>
void check(){
try{
jaegertracing::net::Socket socket;
        socket.open(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM);
        const std::string serverURL = configuration.sampler().kDefaultSamplingServerURL; 
        socket.connect(serverURL);
}catch(...){}
}
```

if it throws error then it is unable to reach host, this method is costly I agree but this is the only viable solution I find